# Is it possible to use GCC without Cygwin or MinGW?

Tags: windows, gcc

[GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is a very well respected multi-language compiler (from what I've gathered). One thing I've not been able to definitively find out is: Is it possible to use GCC on windows ***without*** anything extra like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)?

I've learned that if you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on Cygwin, there is a dependency on a DLL. If you use GCC with MinGW, you eliminate that dependency but you still must have MinGW to use GCC.

Is it possible to build GCC and utilize it by itself, completely native to Windows? Like Microsoft's Compiler?  After reading around, my *guess* is no. But I'd still like more info, if possible.

<del>If not, why does GCC require environments like Cygwin or MinGW?</del> I understand this now. It is because GCC requires a Unix/POSIX environment. **Why** it does, it still beyond me.

I did find this and it helps but doesn't *really* answer my question: [Why does GCC-Windows depend on cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187990/why-does-gcc-windows-depend-on-cygwin)

To refine my question, **I guess what I'm trying**  to understand why GCC can't stand on it's own -- Where I have just "GCC.exe".

Comment: The answer is ideological, Frank. Personally, I'd be happy to see a gcc for windows that doesn't rely on Posix.

Comment: One thing also to note, when you distribute a program built with MSVC, you still have to include redistributable libraries.  With MinGW, you redistribute mingwm10.dll.

Comment: @Mark No you don't. For example, my CSVfix tool compiled with MinGW, is only dependent on MSVCRT.DLL, just like any other windows C/C++ application.

Comment: Also, you don't have to include redistributable libraries with MSVC if you link them statically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For MinGW, you need MinGW in the sense that MinGW provides the implementation of the gcc language system. I don't see how your question makes sense  - it's like "Can I use VC++ without installing VC++?"

**To clarify:**  MinGW is the GCC compiler executable(s), headers and support objects. There isn't anything else. There is a related but independant package called MSYS which provides some posix utilities, but you do not need this in any way in order to use the MinGW version of GCC.

Comment: I can use the compiler without having the IDE installed. I'd just need to compiler executable and any associated header and support objects. I'm not a compiler expert; I don't claim to be. But, I feel my question still stands and makes sense. Perhaps you need to abstract away from some of your assumed knowledge -- your knowledge might be what I'm missing.

Comment: Are you trying to say that MinGW IS, basically, what I'm asking about/for? That it is a version of the GCC that can most closely match what I'm asking about?

Comment: Frank: yes. At least for a large part, if your understand your question correctly.

Afaik mingw is messing with drive mapping schemes too though.

Comment: I've been using Cygwin at the direction of my instructor (for a Master's course). I can switch to MinGW after the class is over.   Also, sorry for deleting my comment and re-posting it. I found a typo and I wasn't sure if the typo interfered with the understanding. So I replaced it.

Comment: @Marco NOOOOO! That is MSYS. MinGW is just the compiler & support stuff - it in no way provides a posix environment and in no way messes with drive mappings.

Comment: Thanks all! Apparently I had a bad assumption... Sorry, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What is exactly the problem with mingw?  And what is native?

mingw used to generate pretty much standalone binaries, and maybe that is even more native than MSVC's, which require msvcrt, a component that needs to be installed sometimes.

So maybe you could explain what you tried with mingw, and what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 2):

To disable mingw's extra dependency  simply don't use exceptions (-fno-exceptions), I haven't used cygwin so not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  I've had to compile some command line apps for people in the past and always had to use cygwin.

I think the biggest reason being posix compatibility, which is what cygwin strives to bring to Win32.

Comment: mingw is getting better . I routinely compile gdb and binutils with it (for cross- purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Linaro used to provide that long time ago, a GCC that runs naively on Windows without MinGW or Cygwin. I am currently using that GCC 4.9 on a Windows 10 PC to compile UEFI and it is working like charm.

https://releases.linaro.org/archive/14.09/components/toolchain/binaries/gcc-linaro-arm-none-eabi-4.9-2014.09_win32.zip

Answer (score 0):

simply install wsl on your computer.