# How to compile Mathematica to C code with intel C++ compiler (x86) on Win7(x64)？

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, wolfram-mathematica, 64-bit, mathematica-8

My OS is windows 7 64bit. I installed Microsoft C++ 2008 Express edition and Intel C++ Compiler v11.1 x86 version.

Now I could successfully compile x86 C code in Mathematica, e.g.

```
    In[1]:= Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
    In[2]:= greeter = CreateExecutable[StringJoin["#include <stdio.h>\n", "int main(){\n", "  printf(\"Hello world.\\n\");\n", "}\n"], "hiworld", 
     "Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`IntelCompiler, 
     "CompilerInstallation" -> "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Compiler\\11.1\\072\\", 
     "CompilerName" -> Automatic, "TargetSystemID" -> "Windows"]

    Out[2]= "C:\\...\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\\
       SystemFiles\\LibraryResources\\Windows-x86-64\\hiworld.exe"
```

But failed to use `CompilationTarget -> "C"` to compile a function like this

```
    In[3]:= f = Compile[{x, y}, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], CompilationTarget -> "C"]

    During evaluation of In[3]:= LibraryFunction::libload: The function compiledFunction5 was not loaded from the file C:\\...\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\ApplicationData\CCompilerDriver\BuildFolder\vax-5844\compiledFunction5.dll. >>
    During evaluation of In[3]:= Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function. >>
```

I guess I need to specify a default `"TargetSystemID"-> "Windows"` since my platform is x64, but don't know how to setting such an option in Mathematica.

Did I miss any point here?

PS: I don't want to install Microsoft Visual Studio recently.

Answer (score 1):

In your [first code block](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers.html#219393929) you specified the compiler that you wanted. In the second you didn't - so it might be that Mathematica does not "know" about the compilers that you have installed.

Run `` Needs["CCompilerDriver`"] `` then `CCompilers[Full]` to see which of your compilers Mathematica knows about. Also maybe look at the global `$CCompilerDirectory`.

If your Intel and/or Microsoft compilers are not showing up, then follow the [Specific Compilers](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers.html#509267359) page of the [CCompilerDriver User Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/Overview.html).
To get your Intel compiler working, I think maybe the following should suffice:

```
$CCompiler = {
 "Compiler" -> CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`IntelCompiler,
 "CompilerInstallation"->"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Compiler\\11.1\\072\\"}
```

That said - if I use the above code to change the directory to my compiler to something wrong, then the first error type I get (before the  `Compile::nogen`) is `CreateLibrary::instl`, not the `LibraryFunction::libload` message that you have. Maybe something is wrong with your default build directory: `$CCompilerDefaultDirectory`...

In response to your PS, the Intel C++ v11.1 compiler for Windows is on the list of compilers that they have tested, so you shouldn't need to install MS Visual Studio. On the other hand, you could try [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html) for Windows via MiniGW or CygWin (also see [SO/187990](https://stackoverflow.com/a/354767/421225)).